# Stata: estadd-weighted dependant var mean (ysumm)

Tags: latex, stata, mean, weighted

I want to add a row for listing the weighted mean of the dependent variable at the bottom of a regression table. Normally, I would run

```
reg y x1 x2 x3
estadd ysumm, mean
eststo r1
esttab r1 using results.tex, replace label title("Title") long nomtitles cells("b(fmt(a3) star)" t(par fmt(2))) stats(r2 N ymean, labels("R-squared" "Observations" "Mean of Y"))
```

However, I have tried two ways to get the weighted mean without success. 
First:

```
reg y x1 x2 x3
estadd ysumm [aw=pop], mean
```

and I get the error:

```
weights not allowed
r(101);
```

Second, I manually enter the weighted means into a matrix and then save it with `estadd`:

```
matrix define wtmeans=(mean1, mean2, mean3)
estadd matrix wtmeans

esttab r1 using results.tex, replace label title("Title") long nomtitles cells("b(fmt(a3) star)" t(par fmt(2))) stats(r2 N wtmeans, labels("R-squared" "Observations" "Mean of Y"))
```

The resulting tex file includes the label "Mean of Y", but the row is blank.

How can I get those weighted means to appear in the tex table?

Comment: Did this answer work for you, or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve today. Part of the solution is to use a scalar command and then refer to that matrix of scalars in the `esttab, stat()` option.

Here's the syntax I am using for a similar problem. It may be slightly different for you since you're pulling a different scalar (I am grabbing p-values for a specific joint F-test), but in essence it should be the same:

```
eststo clear
eststo ALL: reg treatment var1 var2 var3 var4 if experiment
qui test var1 var2 var3 
estadd scalar pvals=r(p)
```

...repeat for other specifications...

```
esttab _all using filename.csv, replace se r2 ar2 pr2 stat(pvals) star( + .1 ++ .05 +++ .01) b(%9.3f) se(%9.3f) drop(o.*) label indicate()
```

So you could do the following:

```
eststo clear
eststo r1: reg y x1 x2 x3
qui sum y [aw=pop]
estadd scalar YwtdMean=r(mean)
esttab r1 using results.tex, replace label title("Title") long nomtitles cells("b(fmt(a3) star)" t(par fmt(2))) stats(r2 N YwtdMean, labels("R-squared" "Observations" "Weighted Mean of Y"))
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Minute comment: use summarize, meanonly when that's all you need.